# How to get ServiceManager in an abstract class

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I writing an application with Zend Framework 2, and Doctrine 2. I have 2 month experience with both technologies.

I using Doctrine repository documents scheme. I need to access current user in repository class. I can't figure out how to get serviceManager instance in repository. I read lot of articles, but still can't understand dependency injection, I need to to manage service in ZF2.
Can someone explain me how to inject service to an abstract class (like base repository)?

Comment: Why do you need the whole ServiceManager? Furthermore, maybe you need to create a separate service which manages your requirements for the user.
You can inject the user into the repository methods too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` to lazy retrieve the `serviceManager`.

Quote from ZF2 documents:

> Additionally, there are some cases where you may want to receive the ServiceManager to lazy-retrieve dependencies; as such, you may want to implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and know more details about the API of the ServiceManager.

See [ZF2 Quick Start - service manager.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html)

But to be honest you should not use any services within your repository classes. Keep them simple and clean just to retrieve data.

And when you call your repository class, you should pass the user like so:

```
$data = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Common\Entity\User')->myMethod($user);
```